# Store checkbox values in PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, checkbox

I have to program an internet site that includes a login. That I did already and it work well. After you logged in I set 4 HTML buttons for 4 different categories (nature, persons, objects, symbols). If you click on one of the 4 buttons there appears a table with Whatsapp Emojis and beside them a checkbox. The images of the WhatsApp Emojis are local stored. The Path of these Emojis are in a SQL Database. The number of the picture is also in the Database stored. The number of the picture is also the name of the checkbox. That means Emoji 1 has the checkbox 1, Emoji 2 the checkbox 2 and so on. And if you click to another category the picture number continues from the last number of the last Emoji from the last category.

This all works fine. Now to my Problem.

For example: If you check a checkbox in the category "nature" and you click to     another category and after that you click back to "nature" the checked checkbox isn't checked anymore.

My idea: Save the checkbox in the session. I know how it works, but in this case it absolutely does not work because I have 4 different categories and I cant save the checked checkbox in the Session.

I have for every category another script! And the buttons lead to this script!

Here is a Picture how it looks like (Sorry, it is German) [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jvXH.png)

objekte.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

**CSS - Stuff**

```
    <h1>Kategorie bitte w&auml;hlen!</h1>

<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='_GET'>
<?php
    $vorname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
    $nachname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
    echo "<p id='loggedAs'>Eingeloggt als: " .$vorname. " ".$nachname." "; 
?>
<?php
    echo "<button type='submit' name='ausloggen'>Ausloggen</button>";
?>  
</form>
</p>


<form action="natur.php" method="_GET">
<input type='submit' name='NaturVonObjekte' value='Natur'>
</form>
<form action="objekte.php" method="_GET">
<input type='submit' name='ObjekteVonObjekte' value='Objekte'>
</form>
<form action="personen.php" method="_GET">
<input type='submit' name='PersonenVonObjekte' value='Personen'>
</form>
<form action="symbole.php" method="_GET">
<input type='submit' name='SymboleVonObjekte' value='Symbole'>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['ObjekteVonNatur']) && isset($_GET['Natur'])){
        echo "Bin hier";
        $natur = $_GET['Natur'];
        $_SESSION['naturbilder'] = $natur;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>\n";

    if(isset($_GET['ObjekteVonNatur']) || isset($_GET['ObjekteVonObjekte'])||isset($_GET['ObjekteVonPersonen'])||isset($_GET['ObjekteVonSymbole'])){

        $db_link = @mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "emojiwahl");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            printf("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM emoji WHERE EKat = 1";
        $erg = mysqli_query($db_link, $sql);

        if (! $erg){
            die('Ungültige Abfrage: Vorname nicht vorhanden' . mysqli_error("1"));
        }

        echo '<table border="1">';

        if (mysqli_num_rows($erg) != "0"){
            echo "<tr>";
            for($i = 0; $i<7; $i++){
                echo "<th>Grafik</th> <th>Auswahlbox</th>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        for($ii = 0; $ii<7;$ii++){
            while($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($erg)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><img src='".$zeile["EPfad"]."'></img></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='".$zeile["ENr"]."' ></td>";
                for($ii = 0; $ii<6; $ii++){
                    if($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($erg)){
                        echo "<td><img src='".$zeile["EPfad"]."' value='".$zeile["ENr"]."'></img></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$zeile["ENr"]."' name='objekte[]' ></td>";
                }
            }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_GET['ausloggen'])){
        session_destroy();
        header('Location:Anmeldung.php');
    }   
?>
```

natur.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

**CSS-Stuff**

```
<form action="natur.php" method="_GET">
<input type='submit' name='NaturVonNatur' value='Natur'>
</form>
<form action="objekte.php" method="get">
<input type='submit' name='ObjekteVonNatur' value='Objekte'>
</form>
<form action="personen.php" method="_GET">
<input type='submit' name='PersonenVonNatur' value='Personen'>
</form>
<form action="symbole.php" method="_GET">
<input type='submit' name='SymboleVonNatur' value='Symbole'>
</form>

<?php

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>\n";

    if(isset($_GET['NaturVonNatur']) || isset($_GET['NaturVonObjekte'])||isset($_GET['NaturVonPersonen'])||isset($_GET['NaturVonSymbole'])){    
        $db_link = @mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "emojiwahl");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            printf("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM emoji WHERE EKat = 0";
        $erg = mysqli_query($db_link, $sql);

        if (! $erg){
            die('Ungültige Abfrage: Vorname nicht vorhanden' . mysqli_error("1"));
        }

        echo '<table border="1">';
        if (mysqli_num_rows($erg) != "0"){
            echo "<tr>";
            for($i = 0; $i<7; $i++){
                echo "<th>Grafik</th> <th>Auswahlbox</th>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        for($ii = 0; $ii<7;$ii++){
            while($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($erg)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><img src='".$zeile["EPfad"]."'></img></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$zeile["ENr"]."' name='Natur[]'></td>";
                for($ii = 0; $ii<6; $ii++){
                    if($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($erg)){
                        echo "<td><img src='".$zeile["EPfad"]."'></img></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$zeile["ENr"]."' name='Natur[]'></td>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['ausloggen'])){
        session_destroy();
        header('Location:Anmeldung.php');
    }

?>
```

The code from the other 3 categories look almost the same as here. I can't store something in the session. From the script "natur" I dont get anything in the script "objekt" to store the checkbox values in the session.

Comment: In order for us to help you solve this we would have to see some markup and code.

Comment: Sorry, here is the Code @JayBlanchard.

Comment: For how long do you want to retain the state of your checkboxes? Like if check some of checkboxes and refresh the page, should these checkboxes be checked when you come back to the page?

Comment: I want to retain this state of my checkboxes still the user pushes the button "Logout" because then I destroy the session. @Mikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to retain the state of your checkboxes for the duration of your page, I think your best option is to query all images from the start, place them into hidden tables on the page based on their categories, and have the buttons toggle (show/hide) the tables using JavaScript. Of course, this is not a good option if you have crazy amount of images.

Here's a quick illustration:

```js
var buttons, tables;

function toggleImages() {
    var button = this;
    // show/hide table depending on whether button's name matches the table's ID
    for (i = 0, len = tables.length; i < len; i++) {
        tables[i].style = tables[i].id === button.name ? 'display: table' : 'display: none'; 
    }
}

window.onload = function (e) {
    buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    // add event listener to all buttons
    for (i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', toggleImages);
    }
    tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
}

// note: easier and safer to do all this with jQuery
```

```html
<button name="natures">Natur</button>
<button name="objects">Objekte</button>
<button name="persons">Personen</button>

<table id="natures" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 1</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="1" ></td>
        <td>Image 2</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="2" ></td>
        <td>Image 3</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="3" ></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="objects" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 7</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="7" ></td>
        <td>Image 8</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="8" ></td>
        <td>Image 9</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="9" ></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="persons" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Picture</th><th>Checkbox</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 4</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="4" ></td>
        <td>Image 5</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="5" ></td>
        <td>Image 6</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="6" ></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to retain the state of your checkboxes even after leaving the page, then your best option is probably to store the values in the database like what FileX said.

You could also store and retrieve the state of your checkboxes in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) depending on how long you need to keep the state of your checkboxes. However, this may affect your browser's performance if you store too much.

Comment: I have a question... I am new in web programming and I don't understand the difference between jQuery and JavaScript. You seem really experienced in web programming, so I would be very grateful, if you can help me. Thanks :)

Comment: First and foremost, JavaScript is a programming language. Most programming language have libraries, which are collections of pre-written functions and objects that you can reuse. For JavaScript, [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is a library. And there are plenty of [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

Comment: Thank you very much! @Mikey

Answer (score 0):

Sessions isn't a good solution to solve this problem.
Sessions is for the actual login session, not for ever.
Save the values temporaly in a table and delete them when the action is done.

Deutsch:
Es ist keine gute Idee das Problem mit Sessions zu lösen.
Sessions ist für die Zeit gedacht, in der man aktuell Online ist und ist solange auch nur aktiv. Sprich wenn man sich ausloggt ist die Session weg. Es wäre besser das ganze über die SQL Tabelle zu speichern, dort ist es etwas kompakter, sprich man kann überall darauf zugreifen.

Comment: I hope you are German so: 

Die Checkboxen sollen auch nur solange gespeichert werden, bis man sich ausloggt. Deshalb dachte ich es wäre eine gut Option gewesen.